# Find the probability distribution of X.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable with cumulative distribution function:

$$F(x)=\begin{cases}
     0 & : x < -2
\\ 1/8 & : -2 \leq x < -1
\\ 3/8 & : -1 \leq x < 0 
\\ 5/8 & : 0 \leq x < 1 
\\ 7/8 & : 1 \leq x < 2
\\   1 & : 2 \leq x \end{cases}$$

a) Find the probability distribution of X.

b) Find the expected value and std deviation of X.

c) Find the $70$th percentile.

d) Find $P(-1\leq X \leq 1)$

My work: I can't attempt b, c, and d without knowing the answer to a.

For *a* I'm not sure how to go about finding the probability distribution from the CDF. I know the CDF is the sum from $y\leq x$ of $f(y)$. I can't understand how to track backwards. I have looked online and on youtube for how to solve this and in all cases I've seen the cdf has functions for the value and from what I understand the cdf is the derivative of the pdf. But I just have numbers, $0, 1/8, 7/8$, the derivative of all of those is just $0$ so I don't think I can apply that to my problem.

Updated: Using @probablyme 's answer for a:

b) E(X) = 0

SD $=(4*1/8)+(1*2/8)+(0*2/8)+(1*2/8)+(4*1/8)+(0*0)=1.5$

c) $70$th percentile = $(6*0.7)=4.2$ round to $5$ thus $70$th percentile = $1/8$

d) $P(-1\leq X \leq 1)$ = F($1$) - F($-2$) = $5/8 - 0 = 5/8$

Comment: No, where did you get $h(x)+f(x)$? Since we have $f(x)$, and it is discrete we can use $\sum_x xf(x)$ Also, by symmetry, it is $0$.

Comment: I meant h(x) times f(x). If the expected value is zero then the standard deviation must be zero too?

Comment: Nope.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I updated my answer. My textbook says SD is (x-∑xf(x))^2 * f(x)

Comment: Now it's right.

Comment: I also put up my answers for C and D.

Comment: For c) 1. I'm not sure what you are doing; 2. I actually not 100% about the answer, but I think it is 0. d) Looks wrong. I think you meant $F(1)-F(-1)$

Comment: Sorry, for c) I meant I think it is 1, not 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the cdf, we can get the following pmf

$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{8}, &x = -2\\[1ex]
\dfrac{2}{8}, &x = -1\\[1ex]
\dfrac{2}{8}, &x = 0\\[1ex]
\dfrac{2}{8}, &x = 1\\[1ex]
\dfrac{1}{8}, &x = 2\\[1ex]
0, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
 because the cdf only changes at $x = -2,-1,0,1,2$. Thus this is the range of $X$, and we see that $X$ is ***discrete***.

In particular $F(-2) = f(-2) = 1/8$, $3/8 = F(-1) = f(-2)+f(-1)\implies f(-1) = 2/8$. The rest are calculated similarly.